# What does Project From View technically do?

Tags: uv

I am trying to strengthen my understanding of how UV's work and I realize that I take certain things for granted.  One of them is "Project From View".

Per the Blender manual:
"Project from View takes the current view in the 3D View and flattens the mesh as it appears."

I've used this feature numerous times but I don't actually understand what is going on, or where the settings are that control this.  Would love some tips to deepen my understanding of this, even if that means going to back to the basics.

Answer (score 3):

*Project from View* does exactly the same thing as creating a 2d image from a 3D object does.  It treats your viewpoint as a square plane parallel to the screen and projects the object onto that square plane.  So, for instance, if I have this view of a cube:

[image: My View of a cube]

It will create this projection:

[image: Projected UV view]

This projection uses a vanishing point at infinity and utilizes the Focal Length of the View "camera" (in the sidepanel, View Tab) as well as the zoom level of your viewpoint.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that Marty.  I'm actually more confused than before!  Lol, I guess I really need to go back to the basics.  I was under the impression that Project From View projected an image onto a 3D object from the perspective you are viewing it.  I was trying to understand technically what this means, in terms of where the settings are for this after you've done it.